# How to replace multiple strings in multiple text files?

Tags: python, rename

SO!  I am fairly new to Python and I have a large series of files that I need to replace certain lines with other lines.

I know this may be a little confusing, but let me explain.

So I have a directory full of files, let's so temp/.

I need to iterate through all the files in that directory, using Python and modify each file, replacing certain lines.

For this, I want to have one file called **newStrings.txt**

```
ReplaceWithThis
iLikeReplacingStuff
```

And I want these strings to replace lines from **oldStrings.txt**

```
I hate this string
Please get rid of me
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Do you want to replace certain keywords in multiple files? Do you want to detect certain patterns in multiple files, then replace them? How do you want to find those files? Should the filenames meet a certain pattern? It's all very "up in the air" at the moment.

Comment: No for example I'm seraching for "HelloWord" and I want to replace it with "ByeWorld" But I have like 152 of those texts I want to rename together because I can't be bothered going through all the files 1 by 1

Comment: If there is this much confusion over what you want perhaps spend the time to read about how to ask a good question on Stack and you will get more relevant answers. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The term _rename_ imply (the name of) a file. The term _replace_ is used with any text. I suggest you to change the topic title (and delete the then unnecessary explanations). Note that all doubts posted here in comments was caused by the use of this sole word...

Comment: In addition, you should add your own attempts; otherwise this is nothing but asking for code, which is off-topic here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code has been tailored per the poster's request.

```
import os

folderLocation = "temp/"

lookup = dict()

with open("newString.txt","r") as values:
    with open("oldString.txt","r") as keys:
        keyLines = keys.readlines()
        valueLines = values.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(keyLines):
            lookup[line] = valueLines[i]


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folderLocation):
    for fileIn in files:
        os.rename(folderLocation + fileIn, folderLocation + "old_" + fileIn)
        with open (folderLocation + "old_" + fileIn, "r") as fi:
            with open(folderLocation + fileIn, "w") as fo:
                for line in fi:
                    if line in lookup:
                        fo.write(lookup[line])
                    else:
                        fo.write(line)
```

Comment: You could store the filenames in a nicer way. What about a list of tuples? Each list entry contains an "old and "new" name bundled together in a tuple. That way there's no faffing around with splitting strings multiple times.

Comment: Well, OldFineName1.txt is not my file name I want to rename texts inside the file names for example I have a file called HelloWorld.txt and there is a word saying "Welcome to world" Inside HelloWorld.txt I wan't to change that "Welcome to world" to something else. I have about 152+ .txt files do you know any good solution?

Comment: Is there any kind of naming convention, like one is temp.old.txt and the other is temp.new.txt ?  You can change the string up there to anything you want, so you could put """example.txt|new_example.txt""".

Comment: If you don't care what the new ones are called, I can simply add new_ to the front of the file names, but I assume your looking for specific changes to the file name.

Comment: No no, For example I have a folder okay? It contains 152 .txt files inside it. I want to select the folder and rename OldFileName1.txt
OldFileName2.txt
OldFileName3.txt to NewFileName1.txt NewFileName2.txt NewFileName3.txt I do not want to change the file names I want to change the text inside the files

Comment: So you don't want to change (rename) file name? And want to replace text inside files? Then what is `OldFileName1.txt|NewFileName1.txt`? Is it not file name?

Comment: Well do you have discord so we can talk better then in the comments?